# ConcurrentAppendException: Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again

Tags: delta-lake

This is the error which is coming while processing concurrent merge in delta lake tables in Azure Databricks .ConcurrentAppendException: Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again.. What are the options to stop this error What are the options to stop this error

To change the isolation level from the default WriteSerializable to Serializable
ALTER TABLE  SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.isolationLevel' = 'Serializable')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure changing the isolation will help you in this case.

Have a look at: https://docs.delta.io/latest/concurrency-control.html#avoid-conflicts-using-partitioning-and-disjoint-command-conditions

They recommend partitioning your data in a way that no two simultaneous processes ever write/read to the same partition, and making the data separation explicit in the update or merge operation you might be performing.

If that's not possible, you might have to catch the ConcurrentAppendException, waiting for a little bit and retrying.